# Change Stack Location for Cortex M3 in Startup.s file

Tags: arm, stack, startup, cortex-m

I am trying to change STACK location for user application. In my system, user application has own RAM section (Data + Stack) andlinker puts STACK at the end of user RAM section. 
But I need to put STACK at beginning instead of end.

I am working with Keil uVision IDE and startup.s file and startup.s file does not provide any option to change location of change STACK location, probably, linker hides it

```
Stack_Size      EQU     0x00000200

                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
Stack_Mem       SPACE   Stack_Size
__initial_sp
```

It is possible to locate STACK in a special address or especially at the beginning of RAM Section?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the linker script look like? Isn't that where the address of the STACK section would be specified?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no linker script in uVision Project. Linker Scripts should be used with GCC compilers/linkers. I just provide startup.s file.

Comment: I confess that I don't know how uVision works, but somewhere, somehow the linker must be told where things are to be located in memory.

Comment: Yes you are right and that's what I am looking for :)

Comment: If you just let the linker to do what it wants it will place things in memory in a way which it see's fit (I think the stack defaults to the end of RAM). If you wish to control this then a scatter file is the way forward (the scatter file is the linker script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I create RAM two regions using scatter file and if I put *(STACK) directive to first one and , it seems OK and STACK is located to start of User RAM. For now, it solves my issue, but possible better solutions exist. 
Thanks.

```
  RW_IRAM1 0x10005000 0x00000200  {  ; STACK
   *(STACK)
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x10005200 0x00000E00  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
```

Comment: I think that you can create just 1 RAM section put the "*(STACK)" on its own line above .ANY. Not 100% sure this guarantees the order so you would have to check,

Comment: @RealtimeRik I had also tried it but did not work. Thanks.